# ckeditor plugin for custom links / tags

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I'm using CKeditor 3.6 and find myself in need of writing a simple plugin. What I need is a button that works much like the format buttons (bold, italic, etc.) except that it will turn this:

SelectedWord

not into, say,

```
<b>SelectedWord</b>
```

but into:

```
<a href="http://www.mywiki.tld/wiki/SelectedWord">SelectedWord</a>
```

I've tried looking into the various plugins that come with CKeditor, but quite frankly, they are more confusing then helpful. I've read the tutorials, I know the basics of writing a plugin, but what eludes me is the functionality itself.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to hack the CKEditor code base, but let me tell you that hacking around ckeditor is not so difficult.  Also, there are versions of the older fckeditor floating around.  Compare the two and see which one would be easier to hack for your mod. I have had to use the older version specifically for creating pinholes against Coldfusion so I could use the file upload segment of the tool. And in another case to function against domain cookies, because of security issues with regular cookies.  FCKEditor and CKEditor has never been a clear install for me with the base product.  I hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: I don't know what's the relation of Tom's age (do you know him?) and the question, that part of your answer isn't needed at all. And suggesting to use an old version that hasn't been developed for over two years is absolutely misleading.